How to escape single quotes in xliff translation file
I want to quote a filename with single apostrophe in a flash message in an easyadmin3/symfony7 app. It looks like it is not possible to use an apostrophe next to a replacement placeholder.
In a controller i set a flash message like this.
$this->addFlash('success', new TranslatableMessage('import.success', [
    'filename' => 'import.csv',
]));

The xliff file contains for the translation keyword the following with some tryouts to quote the filename:
<target>File {filename}-'{filename}'-&apos;{filename}&apos;-"{filename}" imported.</target>

The flash message shown on screen:
File import.csv-{filename}-{filename}-"import.csv" imported.

As you see the {filename} placeholder inside the single quote is not replaced. What is the correct way to escape the single quote in the xliff file?

Update the <target> in your XLIFF file to escape the single quote correctly.
Use the XML entity for an apostrophe (&apos;) or wrap the entire string in double quotes to avoid conflicts.
Here's how you can structure your XLIFF file:
<target>File {filename} - '{filename}' - &apos;{filename}&apos; - "{filename}" imported.</target>

The key difference between your solution and the one I suggested lies in the placement and interpretation of the placeholder {filename} within the quotes.
Hope this works for you

Unfortunately this does not work (in symfony 7.2). And as you see i already used the xml entity. i looked up inside the symfony cache and it looks like both versions (' and ') are replaced by the escaped single quote ('). So this may be a bug in symfony.
